# Cannot read property 'create' of undefined in expressjs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Please am new to Nodejs but am trying to insert a data into my database using sequelize but am getting Cannot read property .create of undefined.

This is my **index.js** file

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')

const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
config.DB,
config.USER,
config.PASSWORD,
{
  host: config.HOST,
  dialect: config.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: config.pool.max,
    min: config.pool.min,
    acquire: config.pool.acquire,
    idle: config.pool.idle
  }
});
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
file !== 'index.js'
)

.forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
    // db[model] = model
    db.User = model
})
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db;
```

This is my **Model/User.js** File

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
sequelize.define('User', {
    hmtec_email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    hmtec_password: DataTypes.STRING
})
```

This is my **Controllers/AuthController.js** File

```
const {User} = require ('../models/User')
module.exports = {
async register (req, res) {
    try {
        const user = await User.create(req.body)
        res.send(user.toJSON())
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Email already in Use'
        })
    }
}
```

I don't know what wrong with the code, I dont know why am getting that error of .create is undefined

Comment: In AuthController type  ``` const user = new User(req.body); await user.save(); ``` instead of ```const user = await User.create(req.body) ```

Comment: I get user is not a constructor...Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the last file .. AuthController.js

```
const {User} = require ('../models/User')
```

You are using the Es6 new destruction assignment

More Info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Normally you should define your variable without the brackets

That mean you got all of the variable available.

But adding the brackets means that you want  to get the child of the object, this child is named user .. and then name the variable also as user
and search these info
From the require file after the equal.

But in your user file .. you are exporting a function .. that does not have any child named user
Thus undefined

Better alternative is to use Classes

More info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

So in user model

```
// Inside your function you need to use sequalize module , iam not familar with it but you must require it to use it 

    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    
    // Define the Class
      class user {
    
    // add the name you want to use for the function - here I used create so the other code also work - also I inserted async because this is asynchronous  and also I removed the sequalize from parameters because you don't need it now after it is required above.
    
    async create (DataTypes) => {
        await Sequelize.define('User', {
            hmtec_email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true
            },
            hmtec_password: DataTypes.STRING
        })
    }
    
      module.exports = user;
```

Now when you require the file in Authcontroller , remove the brackets

```
const User = require ('../models/User')
```

and now you can use `User.create(YOUR_DATA_VARIABLE);`in your authController.js

and if there is any other functions inside this class you also can use them in the same manner.

I hope this fix your problem.

Comment: @HemmyhtecCreatives You are welcome, Don't forget to upvote and accept this as the answer if it did help you with your problem, Happy coding.

Comment: Not working...same error....User.create is undefined

Comment: Well I guess this is not your full code, Ok try this, use your old code , in authController.js remove the brackets in `const {User} = require ('../models/User') ,` change in the same file `const user = await User.create(req.body)`  to  `const user = await User(req.body , sequelize, DataTypes)` - 

and in the first line in User.js - change this `module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {`  

into this 

`module.exports = (body, sequelize, DataTypes) => {`

Now when you want to use the req.body in the user.js file , use body instead